# Does anyone know the reference of a few Arabic words?

Tags: reference-request

Are these words from the Quran or Hadith:

"le Qaumi ya lamun le Qaumi yafqahun le Qaumi yuminun"?

If yes, please state reference. I don't know how to write it in Arabic but I heard these in a sermon.

Answer (score 2):

لقوم يعلمون

people who know.

لقوم يفقهون

people who comprehend

لقوم يؤمنون

People who knows

These are the pronounce of word in the Quran in the end of ayah you can
“Le qaumin” لقوم means for people
“Ya lamun” يعلمون who knows
“Ya faqahun” يفقهون who comprehend
“Yuminon” يؤمنون who believe

Comment: Do you know the number of Ayat and Surat?

Comment: Go to the website: https://quran.com/6:98?store=false&translations=

Comment: Then search for لقوم يعلمون copy and paste the Arabic it will show you where it appeared on the Quran then you can read the translation

Comment: What I meant to ask was that is there any ayat in which these three words have appeared together?

Comment: No, usually scholars and lecturer said:” Allah encourage people to think and work their minds as in the ayah...” then they mentioned the end of the ayah above. That’s it.